# How to checked some checkbox at cgridview?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

Q : how to checked some checkbox at cgridview?

Status : I've done a gridview with checkbox. but I don't know how to pre-check some check box. $current_reviewers is an array. I would like to match with $current_reviewers and checkbox to pre-check at gridview.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'acc-recei-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search_reviewerlist(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => 2,
            'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
                'name' => 'userids[]',
            ),
            'value'=>'$data->id',
            'checked'=>'(in_array($data->id, $current_reviewers) ? 1 : ""',
         ),
        'username',
        array(
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->id',
            //'filter'=>array('style'=>'visible:none'), 
            //'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:0px; display:none; border:none; textdecoration:none'),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:none; border:none;', 'class'=>'user-id'),  
            //'header'=>false,
            //'filter'=>false,
        ),

    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: Thank for your helping me, VibhaJ. The $current_reviewers is an array. but I can solved the problem with bool.dev. Thank bool.dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the `$current_reviewers` variable, it is not accessible within the php expression that is passed as the `checked` value. For this you can use an anonymous function and to use the outside variable, use the `use` keyword:

```php
'checked'=>function($data, $row) use ($current_reviewers){
                return in_array($data->id, $current_reviewers);
}
```

Check the usage of [`use` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php#104136).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array(
            'id'=>'id',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => '50',   
            'checked'=>'($data->id==$current_reviewers)?(1):(0)',   

        ),
```